# oracle 11g forms (class not found exception oracle forms engine mine)

Tags: java, oracleforms

I was working on forms builder and I was able to run the form on internet explorer without any issues, but when I changed the internet connection I get this error when I run the form on the browser:

```
 class not found exception oracle forms engine mine
```

I tried to solve the issue by changing advanced security settings in java in control panel but still the error show.

any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggests the the Forms main jar file (frmall.jar) is not being found.  Check the Java Control Panel. It will likely give you the needed hit as to why it is failing. You likely will need to enable trace level 2+ to see what you need.